# cont Other Associates Records of same category with the latest record in the category

Tags: t-sql

I want to count all the records belong to a category & get the data associated with the latest record as

```
CREATE TABLE #TestTable

(

SomeColumn VARCHAR(1)
,data varchar(50)
,CDate datetime
)

GO

INSERT INTO #TestTable VALUES ('A','abdss',getdate())
INSERT INTO #TestTable VALUES ('A','abserts',getdate())
INSERT INTO #TestTable VALUES ('A','awabs',getdate())
INSERT INTO #TestTable VALUES ('A','abrfgts',getdate())
INSERT INTO #TestTable VALUES ('A','abasds',getdate())
INSERT INTO #TestTable VALUES ('A','abasds',getdate())
INSERT INTO #TestTable VALUES ('A','aberzsdsfs',getdate())
INSERT INTO #TestTable VALUES ('A','abarfzdfs',getdate())
INSERT INTO #TestTable VALUES ('B','abzdsfs',getdate())

--SELECT * , COUNT(SomeColumn) From #TestTable
--GROUP BY SomeColumn 

drop table  #TestTable
```

the required output will be

```
SomeColumn | Data          | Date              |Other Associates Records <br/>
A          | abarfzdfs     |last A record date   |7<br/>
B          | abzdsfs       |last B record date   |0<br/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not specified which version of sql server you are using. But if you are using sql-server 2005+. The maybe something like this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SomeColumn ORDER BY CDate) AS RowNbr,
        COUNT(SomeColumn) OVER(PARTITION BY SomeColumn) AS Counts,
        test.*
    FROM
        #TestTable AS test
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.RowNbr=1
```

Comment: @UmbrellaCorporation : Remember to up vote the answer you think are good. That gives us all a warm fuzzy feeling :P